# How can I hide a window when click a button on a page which is located inside that window? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form and inside of it, there is a dock panel to navigate pages. My problem is I want to hide the WPF form and open a new form when click the button on the page which is located inside the WPF form. The way I did is in the below. But It is not working.

[image]

Code for the Page Button:

```
public partial class SubPnlItems_SK : Page
{
    public SubPnlItems_SK()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAddItems_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PnlTabMenu_SK tabMenu_SK = new PnlTabMenu_SK();
        PnlAddItem_SK pnlAddItem_SK = new PnlAddItem_SK();
        tabMenu_SK.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        pnlAddItem_SK.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void btnViewItems_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Form Code:

```
public partial class PnlTabMenu_SK : Window
{
    public PnlTabMenu_SK()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dockPanel_SK.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlItems_SK.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }

    private void btn_minimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnItems_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dockPanel_SK.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlItems_SK.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

    private void btnISN_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dockPanel_SK.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlISN_SK.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnMRF_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dockPanel_SK.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlMRF_SK.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btnGRN_SK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dockPanel_SK.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlGRN_SK.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: If I read everything correct, your goal is to click on btnItems, close PnlTabMenu_SK, and open SubPnlItems_SK?

Comment: @aca No. SubPnlItems_SK is the page which is in the PnlTabMenu_SK window(Inside the dock panel which is located in the PnlTabMenu_SK). I want to open the PnlAddItem_SK & hide the PnlTabMenu_SK(then SubPnlItems_SK is also autoamtically hidden with the PnlTabMenu_SK)